# Javascript - Convert function that have a least two callbacks style to promise style

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, node-promisify

I moving from callback style to promise style to avoid the callback that made me hard to maintain the code. I use `util` module to import and convert the callback function with `util.promisify()`, but the question is if the function have at least two callbacks. How the function will return in promise form, then how can I manage the code to get the promise from two conditional callback.

Callback style example.

```
loginAccount = async ({email,password},success,unsuccess) => {
    this.db.query(`SELECT id, password FROM account WHERE email = ?`,[email],(err,result)=>{
      if (err) throw err
      if (result.length === 0) {
        unsuccess("ไม่มีบัญชีนี้อยู่ในระบบ ตรวจสอบอีเมลว่าถูกต้องหรือไม่")
        return
      }
      const account = result[0]
      bcrypt.compare(password,account.password,(error,response)=>{
        if (err) throw err
        if (!(response)) {
          unsuccess("รหัสผ่านไม่ถูกต้อง")
          return
        }
        this.getUser(account.id,success,unsuccess)
      })
    })
  }
```

I can convert into promise form like this, but I don't know how to return success or unsuccess.

```
  loginAccount = async ({email,password},success,unsuccess) => {
    const result = await this.query(`SELECT id, password FROM account WHERE email = ?`,email)
    if (result.length > 0) {
      const account = result[0]
      const response = await this.compareHash(password,account.password)
      if (response) {
        return this.getUser(account.id)
      }
      else {
        // return unsuccess
        // Wrong password
      }
    }
    else {
      // return unsuccess
      // No account in the database
    }
}
```

another example of callback style and promise style.

```
registerAccount = async ({firstname,lastname,email,password},success,unsuccess) => {
    this.hasAccount(email,(exist)=>{
      if (exist === true) {
        unsuccess("บัญชีนี้เคยลงทะเบียนไว้แล้ว")
        return
      }
      bcrypt.hash(password,this.saltRound,(err,hash)=>{
        if (err) throw err
        this.db.query(`INSERT INTO account (firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?); 
                      SET @user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT IGNORE INTO role (id) VALUES (@user_id);
                      INSERT INTO student_data (id) VALUES (@user_id); 
                      INSERT INTO profile_image (id) VALUES (@user_id);`,
        [firstname,lastname,email,hash],
        (err,result)=>{
          if (err) throw err
          success()
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

```
registerAccount = async ({firstname,lastname,email,password},success,unsuccess) => {
    const exist = await this.hasAccount(email)
    if (exist) {
      // unsuccess function return
      // account is already exists.
      return
    }
    const hash = await this.generateHash(password,this.saltRound)
    const registerQuery = `INSERT INTO account (firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?); 
                          SET @user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT IGNORE INTO role (id) VALUES (@user_id);
                          INSERT INTO student_data (id) VALUES (@user_id); 
                          INSERT INTO profile_image (id) VALUES (@user_id);`
    const result = await this.query(registerQuery,[firstname,lastname,email,hash])
    
    // success function
  }
```

`this.query`, `this.compareHash` and `this.generateHash`, I'm using the library called `util.promisify()` to get promise function.

`this.query` come from `mysql` query function, `this.compareHash` and `this.generateHash` both are come from `bcrypt.compare` and `brcypt.hash`

`this.compareHash` will compare the hash by using plain password and hash password.

`this.generataHash` will generate the hash by using plain password and salt round to return a hash password.

`this.getUser` function.

```
  getUser = async (id) => {
    const result = await this.query(`SELECT * FROM profile_view WHERE id = ?`,id)
    return result[0]
  }
```

Comment: When promisifying the method, you **remove** both of the `success` and `unsuccess` callbacks. You only fulfill (by `return`ing) or reject (by `throw`ing) the promise created by the `async` function.

Comment: Please show `this.query`, `this.compareHash` and `this.getUser` definitions

Comment: @Bergi I'm showed these definition by editing the post.

Comment: Ah, that's where you were using `util.promisify`, I was wondering already where you were using that after mentioning it.

Comment: Sorry,I  forgot to add a defintion of `this.getUser`,but now I'm added.

Comment: As Bergi says, the notion of 'multiple callbacks' disappears and the Promise either succeeds or it doesn't. How you decide what type of success or failure is up to you e.g. `reject('wrong password')` / `reject('user unknown')` etc.

Comment: @James If it possible that using `resolve()` and `reject()` without creating `new Promise()`?

Comment: @PaweenwatManeechai No, you can't call `resolve()` or `reject()`. As I wrote, in an `async function`, you simply `throw` the error or `return` the result.

Comment: @PaweenwatManeechai no because those callbacks don't exist with `async` / `await`, but the process is still the same i.e. `return 'wrong password'` / `return 'user known'` or whatever logical flow makes sense to your application.

Comment: I don't know that is it correct to use without `promise` I'm using `return` for return the value like `resolve` and `throw Error("Some Message")` like `reject` and using `try/catch`.

Comment: @PaweenwatManeechai Well, now you know that it is correct, even if you didn't know before.

Comment: @PaweenwatManeechai it's _still_ a Promise, you just aren't explicitly creating it when you use `async` / `await`, it's all done under the hood for you (`return` = `resolve`, `throw` = `reject`).